# Android studio update textview every 5 seconds

Tags: android

Hi my app needs a realtime data from database and I'm posting it on my `TextView` and I can't update  the `TextView` as the database updates. I tried using `Timer` but its still the same.

Here is my code,

```
public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();

    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeTimerTask();

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
}

private void stopTimerTask() {
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final AcceptCars Cars = (AcceptCars) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cars");
                    renterLat.setText(Cars.renterLat);
                    renterLng.setText(Cars.renterLng);
                    Log.d(TAG,renterLat.getText().toString());
                    Log.d(TAG,renterLng.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And here is where I get the `Cars.renterLat` and `Cars.renterLng`,

```
public class AcceptCars implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("renterLat")
    public String renterLat;

    @SerializedName("renterLng")
    public String renterLng;

}
```

Comment: updating text should be inside **runOnUiThread**

Comment: yes please do and let me know if you still have any problem

Comment: @Saveen - it's still not updating the textview when I changed the value from the database sir. Even on the Log...

Comment: Is your timer print updated value ?

Comment: So, database is also not updating any values.. right ?

Comment: @Saveen - the database is being updated every5 seconds sir Im not using that right now for testing sir. I update it manually.

Comment: Please try with updated values and how you update manually ? if you haven't any kind of values.

Comment: @Saveen - I just changed it directly from phpmyAdmin sir.

Comment: How will your Android app know that your value in the db has changed?

Comment: @KNeerajLal - Ohh, i thought the timer will do that job too. Well, I guess i'm wrong and I don't know how to do that either. Haha!

Comment: So you probably need to query the (updated or not) value from the db in an inteval.

Comment: No problem just update text inside runOnUiThread now

Comment: @KneerajLal - Can you make an exmple sir. I'm having a hard time to understand sir.... Hehe

Comment: Are you getting the values through a webservice?

Comment: Print the log inside the timer getting values or not ?

Comment: @BatzPogi, if you are familiar with RecyclerView, use that. Use TextView as a n item of recyclerView. You can use a timely check or always keep the connection open with DB. If you List_of_data changes, all you need is to write, mRecyclerVIew.notifyDataChange(); and you are all set!

Comment: @Saveen - It's getting the past value sir and the updated value sir. Haha!

Comment: @KNeerajLal - on an online database? Yes sir.

Comment: @BatzPogi Sorry! but you are looking very confused.. Please try to learn and debug yourself before asking any question

Comment: @Saveen - yes sir, i'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic you should be following. I used a `Handler` instead of a `Timer`. Inside the `run` method you need to call your webservice and get the updated value from the db. Use `runOnUiThread` to update the value to the UI from a `Thread`.

See the code below,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Handler taskHandler = new Handler();
    taskHandler.postDelayed(myTask, 0);
}

private Runnable myTask = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

            queryDb();

            // repeat the task
            taskHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
};

private void queryDb(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // call you webservice
            String data = callWebservice();

            // parse the data in to AcceptCars pojo class
            AcceptCars Cars = parseData(data);

            //update the UI
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    renterLat.setText(Cars.renterLat);
                    renterLng.setText(Cars.renterLng);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TimerTask`s are really hard to deal with IMO. You should use a `Handler` and call `postDelayed` to do something after a certain amount of time.

Alternatively, you can try out this timer class I wrote:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

It is really simple to use.

You can use it like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final AcceptCars Cars = (AcceptCars) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cars");
                renterLat.setText(Cars.renterLat);
                renterLng.setText(Cars.renterLng);
                Log.d(TAG,renterLat.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG,renterLng.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    }
 }, 5000, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use countdown timer.
Here is the link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html